# Take the function $f(x)=8x+120$. Find a function $g(x)$ which contains the point $(0,0)$ and is asymptotic to $f(x)$.

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

Take the function $f(x)=8x+120$. Find a function $g(x)$ which contains the point $(0,0)$ and is asymptotic to $f(x)$ in the first quadrant.

I'm not even sure what kind of function $g(x)$ would be.

My thoughts are that: as $x$ approaches infinity $f(x)=g(x)$. Also at infinity: $g'(x)=8$. It's not quadratic as quadratics do not have asymptotes. Is it some kind of rotated logarithmic function?

Comment: Define $g(0)=0$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x\neq0$.

Comment: I don't think that, even if it is correct, it is an advisable answer. It is sure that the adjective "continuous" should have been mentionned...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $8x+120$ is an asymptote we can write $g(x)=8x+120+h(x)$ where $h(x)$ tends to zero as $x\to\infty$ and $h(0)=-120$ so as to make $g(0)=0$. One such function is $h(x)=\frac{-120}{1+x^2}$, so we have
$$g(x)=8x+120-\frac{120}{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For any constant $C$, the function $f(x)+C\cdot e^{-x^2}$ has the same asymptote as $f$.